# Find index of list entries where value is in between

Tags: python, list

It is hard to find a title for this problem, so let me describe the issue. I have a list of strictly monotonic increasing float values with 0 and 1 being upper and lower boundary, respectively. Further there is a value, and I want to find out between which two values the actual value is.

Consider the following example:

```
li = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1.0]
```

I need a function which basically returns an index of the matching pair. If the value is between 0 and 0.1 (to be exact: 0 <= val < 0.1), it should return 0. Examples:

```
get_index(li, 0.3) = 3
get_index(li, 0.05) = 0
get_index(li, 0.9) = 6
```

My current approach would be to iterate over the list, store the last and current item and use a counter. Basically like this:

```
def get_index(li, val):
    counter = 0
    old_val = None
    new_val = None
    for item in li:
        if new_val is None:
            new_val = item
                continue
            old_val = new_val
            new_val = item
            if old_val <= val and val < new_val:
                return counter
        counter += 1
```

I feel however there must be an easier way. How to do this shorter, easier?

Comment: Why `get_index(li, 0.9)` would be 7 ? do you meant 6?

Comment: @Kasramvd: No, 7 is correct, as 0.9 <= 0.9 and 0.9 < 1.0. This is the seventh pair.

Comment: What do you mean by "matching pair" exactly?

Comment: @Kasramvd: sorry, forget it. Its late... Sure, it should be 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html):

```
>>> bisect.bisect_right(li, 0.3) - 1
3
>>> bisect.bisect_right(li, 0.05) - 1
0
>>> bisect.bisect_right(li, 0.9) - 1
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but `get_index(li, 0.9)` will be `6`

```
def get_index(l, v):
    if 0<=v<=.1:
        return 0
    return l.index(v)

>>>get_index(li, 0.3)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick..

```
  def get_index(li, val):
        return li.index(max( i for i in li if  val >= i ))
```

Answer (score 1):

if your list is always strictly monotonic, a simple and readable code could be the following (even if less pythonic than previous answers):

```
def get_index(li, val):
    for index in range(len(li)-1):
        if (li[index] <= val < li[index+1]):
            return index
    return len(li)   # in case of val is greater than max value of the list
```